# Taylor Series Resulting in nan after sin(90) and cos(120)

Tags: c++, trigonometry, nan

doing a school project. i do not understand why the sin comes out to  `-NaN` when after `sin(90)` and `cos(120)`.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Also, when I put this in an online C++ editor it totally works, but when compiled in linux it does not.

```
// Nick Garver
// taylorSeries
// taylorSeries.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

const double PI = atan(1.0)*4.0;
double angle_in_degrees = 0;
double radians = 0;
double degreesToRadians(double d);
double factorial(double factorial);
double mySine(double x);
double myCosine(double x);

int main()
{
    cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
    cout.width(4); cout << left << "Deg";
    cout.width(9); cout << left << "Radians";
    cout.width(11); cout << left << "RealSine";
    cout.width(11); cout << left << "MySin";
    cout.width(12); cout << left << "RealCos";
    cout.width(11); cout << left << "MyCos"<<endl;

    while (angle_in_degrees <= 360) //radian equivalent of 45 degrees
    {
        double sine = sin(degreesToRadians(angle_in_degrees));
        double cosine = cos(degreesToRadians(angle_in_degrees));
        //output
        cout.width(4); cout << left << angle_in_degrees;
        cout.width(9); cout << left << degreesToRadians(angle_in_degrees);
        cout.width(11); cout << left << sine;
        cout.width(11); cout << left << mySine(degreesToRadians(angle_in_degrees));
        cout.width(12); cout << left << cosine;
        cout.width(11); cout << left << myCosine(degreesToRadians(angle_in_degrees))<<endl;
        angle_in_degrees = angle_in_degrees + 15;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}


double degreesToRadians(double d)
{
    double answer;
    answer = (d*PI)/180;
    return answer;
}

double mySine(double x)
{
    double result = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            result += pow(x, i * 2 - 1) / factorial(i * 2 - 1);
        else
            result -= pow(x, i * 2 - 1) / factorial(i * 2 - 1);
    }
    return result;
}

double myCosine(double x)
{
    double positive = 0.0;
    double negative= 0.0;
    double result=0.0;
    for (int i=4; i<=1000; i+=4)
    {
        positive = positive + (pow(x,i) / factorial (i));
    }
    for (int i=2; i<=1000; i+=4)
    {
        negative = negative + (pow(x,i) / factorial (i));
    }
    result = (1 - (negative) + (positive));
    return result;
}

double factorial(double factorial)
{
    float x = 1;
    for (float counter = 1; counter <= factorial; counter++)
    {
        x = x * counter;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: That's a strong indication you've been hitting undefined behavior in your code somewhere. Also `double factorial(double factorial)` is pretty ambigous.

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly indented. 

Also, why don't you use good old `printf`/`std::cout <<` debugging and print out intermediate results to figure out where things went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer this, a few remarks:

- It's always helpful for your own debugging to keep your code tidy. Remove unnecessary empty lines, make sure your bracketing style is uniform, and properly indent. I did this for you, but believe me, you'll avoid a lot of bugs if you keep up a consistent style!
- you have functions that take `double` as input and return `double`, but internally just use `float`; that should be a red flag!
- your whole `degreesToRadians` would be better to read and only one third as long if you just used `return (d*PI)/180;`

Answers now:

in your `factorial` function, you calculate a factorial for values up to `1999`. Hint: try to figure out the value of *1999!* and look up the maximum number that `float` on your machine can hold. Then look up `double`'s maximum. How many orders of magnitude is *1999!* larger?

1999! is ca. 10^5732. That is a large number, about  **150 orders of magnitude larger** than what a 32bit float can hold, or still **18 orders of magnitude larger** than what a 64bit double can hold. To compare, to store *1999!* in a double would be like trying to fit the distance from sun center to earth center in the typical 0.1µm diameter of bacteria.

Comment: thats crazy but wait so....if i cant use float or double...how can I store a number of this magnitude? I have made the program much more speedy but I have made all variables doubles and am still returned nan. Thanks so much for this wonderful explination

Comment: ha, there's special libraries that are much slower than the native types that can store and handle numbers of arbitrary size. Now, using them doesn't make the **least** sense -- just don't use your taylor series up to the 1000th element; in the end, your result `double` couldn't store the accuracy, anyway, and also, **nobody** needs that accuracy. Actually do an error calculation: What is the maximum difference when you cancel Taylor series after the let's say eighth member? It's really, really small.

Comment: You are truly a god.

Answer (score 2):

(Marcus has good points; I am going to ramble in other directions...)

Look at the terms in a Taylor series.  They become too small to make any difference after fewer than 10 terms.  Asking for 1000 is asking for trouble.

Instead of going for 1000, go until the next term does not add anything, something like:

```
term = pow(x, i * 2 - 1) / factorial(i * 2 - 1);
if (result + term == result) { break; }
result += term;
```

The series would run much faster if you iteratively calculated the `pow` and `factorial` rather than starting over each time.  (But, probably speed is not an issue at this point.)

Float has 24 bits of binary precision.  Beginning perhaps with 13!, you will get roundoff errors in float.  Double, on the other hand, has 53 bits of precision and will last until about 22! without roundoff errors.  My point is that you should have done factorial() in double.

Another problem is that the computation of the Taylor series gets somewhat 'unstable' for bigger arguments.  Intermediate terms become bigger than the end result, thereby leading to other roundoff errors.  To avoid this, a common way to compute sine and cosine is to first fold to between -45 and +45 degrees.  No unfolding, except maybe for the sign, is needed later.

As for why you had trouble on one system but not the other -- Different implementations handle NaN differently.

Once you have gotten the NaN out of the way, try computing the series in reverse order.  This will lead to a different set of roundoff errors.  Will it make *your* sin() closer to the *real* sin?

The 'real' sin is probably computed in hardware with 64-bit fixed-point arithmetic, and will be "correctly rounded" to 53 or 24 bits well over 99% of the time.  (This, of course, depends on the chip manufacturer, hence my 'hand-waving' statement.)

To judge how 'close' your value is, you need to compute ULPs (units in the last place).  This involves looking at the bits in the float/double.  (Beyond the scope of this question.)

Sorry about the TMI.

Comment: thanks so much! but i have one question. My outputs for sin(180) and 360 are very very close to 1 and 0 but are showing as a huge decimal. how can I display it as just 1 or 0

Comment: I mentioned "roundoff error" a few times.  That is the cause.  I did not list all the cases.  `degreesToRadians` is another one -- 90 degrees _cannot_ be exactly represented in binary (or decimal) in Radians.  So the `x` argument is already "wrong"...

Comment: For writing a 'good' sin/cos with _degrees_ as an argument, fold _in degrees_ _before_ performing the power series.

Comment: That is, `sind(180)` would map to `sind(0 degrees)`, which becomes `sin(0 radians)` which becomes exactly 0 by your formula.  `sind(181)` become `sind(-1 degrees)` becomes `sin(-0.017... radians)` which will have very few roundoff errors.  Much less error than sin(3.159...) = 3.159 - 5.254 + 2.621 - ...  Keep in mind that things are lost after the 53rd _significant_ digit.  For 5.254, that's only the 50th bit after the decimal point.

Comment: Isn't floating point fun?  (I started playing with this stuff on a Burroughs B-220 in the 1960's.)

Comment: That's about when I got tired of C++ and went to Perl and PHP.

Comment: The goal is to compute sin() (etc) with as few terms as possible and with as few roundoffs as possible (for a given percision of, say, 53 bits).  After the Taylor Series, look at the Maclaurin Series, which lets you eliminate a couple of terms by tweaking the coefficients of the Taylor Series, and tossing the long tail.